# Clarification on the proof for the Inverse Mapping Theorem presented by Serge Lang

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

In the book we are presented a proof for the inverse mapping theorem which I understand for a) and b) but fail to fully understand understand for c).

[image: Inverse Mapping Theorem]
[image: Proof 1c]

My approach:

The way I understand it is that after we let $w=z-z_0$ and define $F(w)= f(z)-f(z_0)= \sum a_nw^n$ . Then we set $w=0 =>F(w)=0$. From there we apply the previous discussion for $0$ and we arrive that $G(w)$ and $F(w)$ beeing inverses.

But from here I am puzzled, we haven't proved that $G(w)$ is analytic and Serge Lang also included the line " Let $w_0=f(z_0)$ and let $g(w)=G(w-w_o)+z_0$" ,which is the same as $g(w)=G(w)+z_o$, and I can't figure out why this line implies the result. Furthermore, in the theorem we have the bit "Suppose that $f'(z_0) \neq 0$" which I don't see beeing used anywhere in the proof. Can anybody please clarify the proof that Lang intended?

Comment: All your questions regard the proof of part b) where then also with $a_1=f'(z_0)$ the condition $f'(z_0)\ne 0$ is used in the inverse function theorem. The latter even leads back to part a), where $a_1=f'(z_0)\ne 0$ is used in the construction of the formal inverse series. So you would also have to provide the proof of b) and at what point you can no longer follow it.

Comment: I cannot follow it after "let $g(w)=G(w-w_0)+z_0$. Also thanks for explaining the derivative part.

Comment: That $G$ is analytic follows from b) and is cited in the first part of c) when "$V_0$ is contained in the disk of convergence of $g$" which implies the condition that $g$ has a positive radius of convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof is not really well written. I'll try to sketch what is going on. 
First make the reduction to $z_0 = f(z_0) = 0$. Being $f$ analytic we have that the $f$ has a power series expansion at $0$ that converges in some open neighborhood of $0$. From $f'(0) \neq 0$, we see that $f$ has a formal inverse $g$ by item (a). (Here is where he uses that the derivative does not vanish). By item (b), $g$ converges in some neighborhood of $0$ i.e. $g$ is also an analytic function.

Then he proceeds to prove that $g$ is in fact an inverse to $f$ for a good choice of neighborhoods $U_0$ and $V_0$.

**Added:** Here I am adding a clarification to the reduction step. I hope this is easier to follow as the coordinate changes are written as compositions of maps.

We have two translations $T_{z_0}(z)= z+z_0$ and $T_{w_0} =w+w_0$ where $w_0=f(z_0)$. Then $$F(z) = \left(T_{w_0}^{-1} \circ f \circ T_{z_0}\right) (z) = f(z+z_0)-w_0$$ 
From this we see that $F(0) = f(z_0)-w_0 =0$. Then Let $G$ be the inverse of $F$ and define $$g(w) = \left( T_{z_0} \circ G\circ T_{w_0}^{-1}\right)(w)= G(w-w_0)+z_0$$
By construction, $f(z) = \left(T_{w_0} \circ F\circ T_{z_0}^{-1}\right)(z)$. Hence

$$f(g(w)) = \left(T_{w_0} \circ F\circ T_{z_0}^{-1}\circ T_{z_0} \circ G\circ T_{w_0}^{-1}\right)(w) = \left(T_{w_0} \circ F\circ  G\circ T_{w_0}^{-1}\right)(w) =\left(T_{w_0} \circ T_{w_0}^{-1}\right)(w) = w $$

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.
Also,  do you know what the $g(w)=G(w-w_o)+z_0$ is for? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You begin with $f$, translate $z_0$ and $w_0=f(z_0)$ to the origin. This gives $F$. We build the inverse $G$ for $F$ and then translate back to give $g$ the inverse of $f$.

Comment: Hey, I think I have worked out the proof for the desired expression. Is that correct? From the original expression we have

$g(w)-z_0=G(w-w_0)$,

$F(g(w)-z_0)=w-w_0$,

$f(g(w))-a_0=w-f(z_0)$,

$w-a_0=w-a_0$,
LHS=RHS

Comment: I added some lines about that